# Making a method for an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, netbeans, average

I have an array that takes student grades from an input. I have to make a method that will find the average of the numbers within the array. Here is the code i have so far...

```
int mark = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
    if(mark <= 100){
    marks.add(Integer.parseInt(input.getText()));  
    input.setText("");
    warningLbl.setText("");
    }
    else{
        warningLbl.setText("Please enter an number between 0-100");
    }
```

I want to take the contents in the array 'marks' and get an average for them then append it in my text area

```
   public static double getAverage(int[] marks)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i : marks) sum += i;
    return ((double) sum)/marks.length;
}
```

This is the method i have to find the average, but i dont know how to use this method and get it to print in a text area

Comment: Sometime it's better clearly your programming language !

Comment: You seem to be asking "how to calculate the average of elements within an array"; yet your code shows no effort of such a calculation. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the average stored in an array , try the following function.

```
public static double average(int[] marks)
{
int sum = 0;
double average;
for(int element: marks)
{
    sum = sum + element;
}
average = (double)sum / marks.length;
return average;
}
```

Hope it helps ! :)

The above method is used to find average in an array(primitive type) , but to find average in List type array(wrapper class) , we have to iterate through each element in the list by this way and do the required calculations :

```
public static String average(Integer[] marks)
{
int sum = 0;
double average;
for (int i = 0; i < marks.size(); i++) 
{
    sum = sum + marks.get(i);
}
average = (double) sum / marks.size();
String averageString = Double.toString(average);
return averageString;
}
```

This returns your average in string type directly.

Comment: Thank you! Another quick question, how would i get this value into my text area?

Comment: Now we are returning average as double type , so we need to convert this to a string first , if you need to get this value in your text area , so you can use this line for that :
String resultInString = Double.toString(average(marks));

Now you can use the string "resultInString" , to put in your text area.

Comment: marks is underlined in red with an error that says "incompatible types: List<Integer> cannot be converted to int[]"

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what to do! Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your current code.

Using `input.getText();` twice will mean it's going to prompt for input twice. Have a single line like `int mark = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());` then use the `mark` variable wherever it's needed.

In order to test if the number is between 0 and 100 (I'm assuming this needs to be inclusive), that if statement would need to be `(mark >= 0 && mark <= 100)`.

I assume you want to get multiple students' grades/marks, so it may be a good idea to enclose your code in a `for` or `while` loop, depending on how you want it to operate. However, since this will be of variable length I'd recommend using a `List` over an array for resizing.

Finding the average is easy. Just use a `foreach` loop to sum up all the numbers, then divide that by the array length.